# "AT least one signature is invalid" error message after removing signature from pdf using itext

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I have a digitally signed pdf with multiple signatures. Now I want to remove only one of the signatures. I am using itext for the same. The code is as follows:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src_path);

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest_path));


         {
                AcroFields.Item item =        stamper.getAcroFields().getFieldItem(fieldname);

                ClearSignatureDictionary(item.getMerged(0));
                ClearSignatureDictionary(item.getWidget(0));
                ClearSignatureDictionary(item.getValue(0));
            }
        }

 private static void ClearSignatureDictionary(PdfDictionary dic)
  {
    dic.remove(PdfName.AP);
    dic.remove(PdfName.AS);
    dic.remove(PdfName.V);
    dic.remove(PdfName.DV);
    dic.remove(PdfName.SV);
    dic.remove(PdfName.FF);
    dic.put(PdfName.F, new PdfNumber(4));
 }
```

But when I open the document with the removed signature, it gives me the following error on Acrobat reader
"At least one of the signatures is invalid"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not remove keys from a dictionary in a signed document, and expect the signatures to remain valid. You can only remove the last signature that was added. If a document was signed by multiple people, and you want to remove the first signature, all subsequent signatures will be broken.

This image explains why:

[image]

This image shows that every new digital signature keeps the original bytes intact. With every new signature new bytes are added. Rev1 represents the bytes of a document that has 1 digital signature. Rev2 represents the bytes of a document that has 2 digital signatures. The second digital signatures signs Rev1 completely. If you'd remove the first signature, the second signature would become invalid.

A digital signature is a special type of form field. With iText, you can get the names of the signature form fields of a PDF like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
ArrayList<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();
```

You can only remove the signature that covers the whole document, for instance, if we have `"sig1"`, `"sig2"`, and `"sig3"` (added in that order), only `fields.signatureCoversWholeDocument("sig3")` will return true.

You can get the total number of revisions like this: `fields.getTotalRevisions()` and a specific revision like this: `fields.getRevision("sig1")` (provided that there's a signature field named `"sig1"`).

Suppose that the image represents your document, and you have to remove 1 signature, then you can only remove the third signature by removing all the bytes that were added in revision 3 (Rev3). With iText, that means going back to revision 2 (Rev2). That revision was signed using the signature field `sig2`.
You can extract this revision like this:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("revision2.pdf");
byte bb[] = new byte[1028];
InputStream ip = fields.extractRevision("sig2");
int n = 0;
while ((n = ip.read(bb)) > 0)
    os.write(bb, 0, n);
os.close();
ip.close();
```

The file `revision2.pdf` will be the file signed by `"sig1"` and `"sig2"` without the bytes that were added when creating `"sig3"`.

Comment: Does that mean I cannot delete more than one signature individually?

Comment: You can remove more than one signature at once, but only by going to a specific revision. I am going to ignore your comment that using `fields.signatureCoversWholeDocument("sig3")` causes the same error because that doesn't make sense. Checking if a signature covers the whole document is **a read-only operation**. As you can't change a document with that function, you can't break a signature with it.