# iText or iTextSharp： when i use the ‘PdfStamper’ , target file use adobe.reader Verify signature failure

Tags: java, c#, itext

i want remove the last signature and other signature also can use adobe.reader verify_sign success.

the original file is signed and use adobe.reader verify signature success，but when i do this code(i not remove the signature)， the target file use adobe.reader verify signature failed. but when i use adobe.reader open them, their content show ok.

i doubt the function ·PdfStamper· destroyed the signature data. How should i avoid this problem ？

i use itext and itextsharp (Java and C# ) , They are all this problem. itex and itextsharp version is 5.5.10

i find the url  ["AT least one signature is invalid" error message after removing signature from pdf using itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919205/at-least-one-signature-is-invalid-error-message-after-removing-signature-from?answertab=active#tab-top)        it has removed the signature show falied, but i not remove signature, only 'new PdfStamper' ,the target file use adobe.reader verify signature faild.

thanks~

```
PdfReader re = new PdfReader(filePath);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(re, new FileStream(temfilePath, FileMode.Create));
//TODO temfilePath verify signature failed.        
/*
 *    // not do this code
 *     //just remove the last signature.
 *     AcroFields acro = re.AcroFields;
 *     List<string> list = acro.GetSignatureNames();
 *     int i = 0;
 *     foreach (string s in list)
 *       {
 *           if (list.Count == i)
 *           {
 *               acro.ClearSignatureField(s); acro.RemoveField(s);
 *           }
 *           i++;
 *
 *       }
 */     
 pdfStamper.Close();
 re.Close();
```

Comment: There are two major issues in your approach: **a** you stamp a signed pdf without using append mode which automatically damages all signatures in the file, and **b** you try to change the form field structure of a signed pdf in a pdf update in a manner disallowed for any type of signature.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand your use case correctly. Do you want to rollback the pdf to the state signed by the signature before the outermost one? Then Bruno's answer tells you exactly what to do. Or do you only want to remove the outermost signature but keep all other changes (e.g. form fill-ins) since that previous signature? Then your task is non-trivial...

Comment: *Or do you only want to remove the outermost signature but keep all other changes (e.g. form fill-ins) since that previous signature?* That would be a very strange requirement. I wonder which use case would require this.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie *"That would be a very strange requirement. I wonder which use case would require this."* - There are stranger things out there. E.g. many people forget to take their respective towel along...

Comment: @mkl We're not the 25th yet. Today, we bring our light sabre.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie **Don't ever forget your towel!** A light saber is a nice toy but does it provide nutrients? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The signatures are broken because *you* break them. Please read the [signatures documentation](https://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html) on the [official website](https://itextpdf.com) and you'll find the [Signatures](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-12#481-signatures.java) code sample.

```
public void extractFirstRevision(
    String src, String dest, String sigName) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    byte bb[] = new byte[1028];
    InputStream ip = af.extractRevision(sigName);
    int n = 0;
    while ((n = ip.read(bb)) > 0)
        os.write(bb, 0, n);
    os.close();
    ip.close();
}
```

These are the parameters you need:

- `src`: the path to the signed source file
- `dest`: the path to the file you want to create
- `sigName`: the name of the signature field for which you want to extract the revision

**Update 1:**

In a comment, you say you want to remove the signature but not the content (of the signature?) which is what we generally call *flattening*. That's explained in the [FlattenSignature](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5/remove-digital-signatures) example:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();
```

Now you won't see any signature panel anymore, but the signature widgets will be maintained.

**Update 2:**

In another comment, you clarify that you want to remove a field, and that this operation breaks one of the signatures in the PDF. Yesterday, you posted the question [The saved file is not the same size as the original file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146731), and I answered by referring to the FAQ: [Why do PDFs change when processing them?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-do-pdfs-change-when-processing-them)

For reasons unknown to me, you deleted that question, yet one of the root causes of your current problem is explained in that FAQ. Allow me to copy/paste from that answer:

> ```
> PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
> ```
>
> This creates a new PDF file in which objects are being reordered. You
>   can use PdfStamper in append mode by changing this line into:
>
> ```
> PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
>     new FileOutputStream(dest), '\0', true);
> ```
>
> Now you are creating an incremental update of your PDF file.

You are using `PdfStamper` in a way that reorganizes the objects in the PDF. By doing so, you break the signature (see the first line of my answer). If you don't want to break the signature, you need an *incremental update*. An incremental update doesn't change anything to the original bytes, which keeps the signature valid.

I haven't tested this, but in theory, you could try to remove the second signature in append mode. This wouldn't remove the second signature from the file (it would still be there because of the incremental update), but people opening the PDF in a PDF viewer would no longer see the signature because the relevant objects would be set to inactive in the cross-reference table.

While this "solution" might work in theory, it's highly unlikely that this is the solution you want. However, your use case is very unusual, and I doubt if there is a technical way to achieve it. As I explain in the comments, one of the steps in your workflow should already cause the first signature to break.

Comment: Extracting the previous signed revision is not necessarily the same as removing the outermost signature. There can be in-between unsigned revisions with other changes, e.g. form fill- ins. Even in the same outermost incremental update there can be changes in addition to the signing. As I understand the OP, though, he wants to only remove the signature. (I have to admit,  though, that I'm not sure I correctly understood him...)

Comment: my pdf file has two signature and them can all verify signature. now i use  the code above（the code of Bruno Lowagie） can remove the last signature . i understand the function 'extractRevision' can remove the content of  before the last signature . if i want only remove the last signature and not remove the content, what should i do ? can this idea be realized?  thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to *flatten* the signatures? I'll update my answer, but if that's not what you need, you'll have to clarify.

Comment: @xuelang0204 Please share an example file for which your requirements make a difference and sketch the desired result.

Comment: sorry,I have a problem with my description. I describe the process and the results. 1、create PDF file and write content "ABCDEFG". 2、use "picture A" sign the PDF file .3、append the pdf file with content "HIJKLM". 4、use "picture B" sign the PDF file .signature picture A and B can verify signature ok. now I want remove "picture B with signature data)", get the file with content "ABCDEFG"、"Signature picture A"、"HIJKLM" and verify signature picture A ok(the pdf file is the process 3). Is my description clear? thanks

Comment: Depending on how you do step 3, there's a high chance that step 3 will break signature A due to the very nature of digital signatures. One major mistake you are making if you want to preserve signature A: you aren't using `PdfStamper` in append mode.

Comment: @xuelang0204 As Bruno said, step 3 already breaks signature A if by *'append the pdf file with content "HIJKLM"'* you mean *adding new page content* and not *setting some field content* or *adding an annotation with that content*. But you claimed before that your "*pdf file has two signature and them can all verify signature*", so I assume you actually mean field fill-ins or annotations. To prevent such misunderstanding you really should share an example PDF representative for your issue with "ABCDEFG", "Signature picture A", "HIJKLM", and "Signature picture B".

Comment: thanks  mk and Bruno Lowagie.  the code <PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileOutputStream(dest), '\0', true);  >  Solve my problem.

Comment: OK @xuelang0204, in that case, please accept the answer. Also be aware that the original signature is still hidden in the document. A specialized will be able to find it using the right tools.

Comment: but it gives me the following error on Acrobat reader "At least one of the signatures is invalid".this is a problem or normal phenomenon? Can it be solved?

Comment: @xuelang0204 *"but it gives me the following error ... Can it be solved?"* - please share the file before and after signature removal for analysis.